# Sitecore 6.5 rev. 120247 media urls adding a leading slash

Tags: url, media, upgrade, sitecore

To be able to use Edgecast CDN, we had to write a custom media provider which worked well with before the site was upgraded from 6.5 rev 111230 to 120427. After the upgrade, none of the images showed up on the website. I debugged the code and found a probable cause. In the upgrade following fix was included -

By default, media URLs will now be generated relative to the site root (such as /~/media/images/picture.ashx or /virtualFolder/~/media/picture.ashx) instead of relative to the current page. Such URLs are considered SEO friendly, and also improve caching. (346213, 332285)

This is now adding a leading slash "/" at the beginning of the media urls. So urls are not getting generated as "//mediaserver/abc.jpg". The 'MediaUrlOptions.VirtualFolder" is being set to "/" by default. I want to confirm that this is the issue and also if I can override this in code but I want to find out if this can be controlled from the config file instead of making this change in the code.If this is not the issue then how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you provide some of your sample code that renders these images? Are you using 1FieldRenderer1 controls on the front-end or the C# API?

Comment: I would probably try to contact Sitecore, they might know what has happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the interest of providing the answer here:

Remove the slash in the Media.MediaLinkPrefix setting due to Sitecore automatically adding it now: 
`<setting name="Media.MediaLinkPrefix" value="/mediaserver" />`

As well as in the following one:
`<handler trigger="/mediaserver/" handler="sitecore_media.ashx" />`

Also, Media API improvements have been made since version 6.5.0 rev. 120427. Now it is possible to elegantly override the MediaProvider class using a web.config setting per reference number 312358 in release notes on  the SDN:
http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%206/ReleaseNotes/ChangeLog.aspx

Comment: I didn't write this media provider. Another developer did who left the company so I was going in circles. That did it. Thanks so much.